# TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, root-framework

I keep getting an error when trying to run the `rmakeprofile` command. I get an error saying that 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'.

```
from array import array
from ROOT import gROOT, TCanvas, TProfile, TGraph

class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.p = TProfile()
        self.data = []
        for line in s:
            if not line.startswith("#"):    #Removes Commented lines
                columns = line.split(',')   #Splits into Columns
                if columns:
                    datum = {
                          "threshold" : float(columns[1]),
                          "count" : float(columns[2]),
                          "rate" : float(columns[2]) /float(columns[0]),
                          "scantime" : float(columns[0])
                          }
                    self.data.append(datum)
                    print columns[1], float(columns[2])/float(columns[0])

    def rmakeprofile(self, data, xval, yval, noBins):
        self.a = array('d')
        for datum in data:
            self.a.append(float(datum[xval]))
        self.p = TProfile('p','',noBins,min(self.a),max(self.a))
        for datum in  data:
            self.p.Fill(datum[xval],datum[yval])
        return self.p
```

Here is the traceback:

```
p = d.rmakeprofile(data,"threshold","rate",13)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "ray.py", line 27, in rmakeprofile
self.a = array('d')
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: How did you create `d`?  Is it an instance of `Data`, or is it the `Data` type (or some other type object)?

Comment: The only way I am able to produce the same error is when I replace `self.a = array('d')` with `self.a = array['d']`. You did not accidentally use `[]` instead of `()` at some point, did you?

Comment: I have done. I previously used [] instead of () and that caused the problem. I had not updated the code properly before I ran it again.

Comment: I also was importing information that the class already contained and had called one of my variables the same name as the class name. This has all been cleared up.

Comment: If it has been resolved, shouldn't someone close this question?

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following replacements.

```
    import numpy as np
    self.a = np.asarray(['d'])
```

or even this also works

```
    import numpy as np
    self.a = np.asarray('d')
```